# Django error only on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates, django-views, mysql-error-1242

Locally I use sqllite3 as a database, but in production I use MySQL. When I moved my project to production I encountered this error:

```
  ...
File "S:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\i18n.py", line 46, in
render
    langs = self.languages.resolve(context)
  File "S:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 653, in res
olve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "S:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 692, in _re
solve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r", (bit, current
)) # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [LANGUAGES] in u'[{}, {}, {}]'
```

**I'm using django's i18n**

Any ideas on where this is coming from? Google didn't inform much, also what data would be useful to look at for debugging? I pointed my local test environment to the production DB and got the same error.

My LANGUAGES var in settings.py is:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en',gettext('English')),
    ('fr',gettext('French')),
)
```

**EDIT**
With debug turned on I get the error:

```
Caught OperationalError while rendering: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')
```

on the line `{%  for f in frames %}`

My Frame model is:

```
@I18n('title','description')
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="collection/images",null=True)
    rollover = models.ImageField(upload_to="collection/images",null=True,blank=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

@I18n('title')
class Frame(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    collection = models.ManyToManyField(Collection)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="frame/images")
    rollover = models.ImageField(upload_to="frame/images",null=True,blank=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**EDIT #2**

The troublesome MySQL lines, that doesn't fail in SQLite

```
SELECT `FrontEnd_article`.`id`, `FrontEnd_article`.`title_fr`, `FrontEnd_article`
.`title_en`, `FrontEnd_article`.`text_fr`, `FrontEnd_article`.`text_en`, 
`FrontEnd_article`.`date`, `FrontEnd_article`.`image`, `FrontEnd_article`.`image_text`, 
`FrontEnd_article`.`can_comment`, `FrontEnd_article`.`order`, 
`FrontEnd_article`.`publish` FROM `FrontEnd_article` INNER JOIN 
`FrontEnd_article_frames` ON (`FrontEnd_article`.`id` = 
`FrontEnd_article_frames`.`article_id`) WHERE `FrontEnd_article_frames`.`frame_id` =  
(SELECT U0.`id` FROM `FrontEnd_frame` U0 INNER JOIN `FrontEnd_frame_collection` U1 ON 
(U0.`id` = U1.`frame_id`) WHERE (U1.`collection_id` = 1  AND U0.`publish` = True )) 
ORDER BY `FrontEnd_article`.`date` DESC
```

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the traceback the same if you enable DEBUG temporarily? Error messages can be misleading when it is disabled. It could as well be a wrong database setting and Django bails out at a different stage.

Comment: Wow Thanks for that tip! I guess I was partially chasing a red-herring. I'm now getting this error...

Caught OperationalError while rendering: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Comment: How does the db query which causes the error look like? Does it use the orm or is it raw sql? Obviously the query contains sql which is valid in sqlite but not in mysql and thus an OperationalError is raised.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM FrontEnd_article INNER JOIN FrontEnd_article_frames ON 
(FrontEnd_article.id = FrontEnd_article_frames.article_id) WHERE 
FrontEnd_article_frames.frame_id = (SELECT U0.id FROM FrontEnd_frame U0 INNER JOIN 
FrontEnd_frame_collection U1 ON (U0.id = U1.frame_id) WHERE (U1.collection_id = 1  AND 
U0.publish = True ))
```

This is the simplified version of what is generated by Django. When I broke down this query I realised that inner join assumes that only 1 value is returned from:

```
(SELECT U0.id FROM FrontEnd_frame U0 INNER JOIN FrontEnd_frame_collection U1 ON 
(U0.id = U1.frame_id) WHERE (U1.collection_id = 1  AND U0.publish = True ))
```

Which in fact returned a result set of data. The fix was simple once I found it, I replaced the "=" with an "IN" and it worked correctly.

```
FrontEnd_article_frames.frame_id IN (SELECT U0.id FROM FrontEnd_frame U0 INNER JOIN
FrontEnd_frame_collection U1 ON (U0.id = U1.frame_id) WHERE (U1.collection_id = 1  AND 
U0.publish = True ))
```